# Sharepoint 2010: Unable to see Site Collections Administration

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm new to sharepoint and I'm having trouble getting the "Site Collections Administration" section to appear under "Site Actions -> Site Settings".

I read on another site, that I need to logon as a site collections administator.  Since I wasn't yet an admin, I logged into Sharepoint Central Administration -> Site Collections -> Change site collection administrators.  From within here, I set myself as a secondary site collection admin.  So far so good.

Next, I logged back into sharepoint with my user account, which I'm assuming, now had permissions to site collection, however when I went back into Site Settings, I still can't see "Site Collections Administrator"

My current permissions are listed as "Full Control, Design".

Any idea why I can't see this section?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Site collection administrators** link will not appear under *Users and Permissions* unless you are at the Site Collection Top Level Site.

You can verify where you are by going to *Site Actions* > **Site Settings**. If under the *Site Collection Administration* section, it says *Go to top level site settings* you are not at the Top Level Site. Click this link to get the top level site.